# How to solve "throw er; // Unhandled stream error in pipe" error?

Tags: ember.js, npm, ember-cli

After installing Ember CLI on a OS X 10.9.3 system I can't use `ember new my-new-app` as shown on https://github.com/stefanpenner/ember-cli

I get the following error:
[image]

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You screwed up your npm installation, your user doesn't have access rights to this file.

Best solution (barring much better understanding of node on both sides) is to try and reinstall node. Can't help you there, don't know what method you used to install it. I had pretty good experiences using homebrew.

You can also try: `sudo chown -R stefan:stefan ~/.npm/`. I, however, can't guarantee there won't be long term bad consequences from doing this (theoretically, there shouldn't).

Finally, if you just want to get past the error, try this: `sudo ember new my-new-app`. You will, however, probably have to keep using `sudo` for every little thing, so it's not recommended.